# Grails 2.4.4 and joda-time plugin not working

Tags: grails, jodatime, grails-2.4

I have been struggling with this for 2 days now and everything I've read so far does not seem to work.   Is it possible to use the joda-time plugin with Grails 2.4.4? Has anyone done this? I created a brand new 2.4.4 application, made a domain class, and just added the joda-time plugin and I get the following error at run time

Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [Domain Name Here]:  No such property: org for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder

I've tried versions of the plugin up to 1.6-SNAPSHOT but nothing seems to work.

Comment: how your domain class looks?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in it of consequence.  class MyDomain {

    Long id
    String typeName

    static constraints = {
      typeName(unique:true)
    }
}

Comment: I do not think this is a problem but try to remove "Long id" from domain class, you do not need it.
And what hibernate version are you using? Also anything specific in buildConfig.groovy?